# Is there a way to do a load balancing between pod in multiple nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

I have a kubernetes cluster deployed with rke witch is composed of 3 nodes in 3 different servers and in those server there is 1 pod which is running yatsukino/healthereum which is a personal modification of  ethereum/client-go:stable .
The problem is that I'm not understanding how to add an external ip to send request to the pods witch are

My pods could be in 3 states:

1. they syncing the ethereum blockchain
2. they restarted because of a sync problem
3. they are sync and everything is fine

I don't want my load balancer to transfer requests to the 2 first states, only the third point consider my pod as up to date.

I've been searching in the kubernetes doc but (maybe because a miss understanding) I only find load balancing for pods inside a unique node.

**Here is my deployment file:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: goerli
  name: goerli-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: goerli
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: goerli
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: yatsukino/healthereum
          name: goerli-geth
          args: ["--goerli", "--datadir", "/app", "--ipcpath", "/root/.ethereum/geth.ipc"]
          env:
          - name: LASTBLOCK
            value: "0"
          - name: FAILCOUNTER
            value: "0"
          ports:
          - containerPort: 30303
            name: geth
          - containerPort: 8545
            name: console
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - /app/health.sh
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 60
          volumeMounts:
          - name: app
            mountPath: /app
      initContainers: 
      - name: healthcheck
        image: ethereum/client-go:stable
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "wget -O /app/health.sh http://my-bash-script && chmod 544 /app/health.sh"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app
          mountPath: "/app"
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: app
        hostPath:
          path: /app/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers above explains the concepts, but about your questions anout services and external ip; you must declare the service, example;

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: goerli
spec:
  selector:
    app: goerli
  ports:
  - port: 8545
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The `type: LoadBalancer` will assign an external address for in public cloud or if you use something like [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/). Check your address with `kubectl get svc goerli`. If the external address is "pending" you have a problem...

If this is your own setup you can use `externalIPs` to assign your own external ip;

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: goerli
spec:
  selector:
    app: goerli
  ports:
  - port: 8545
  externalIPs:
  - 222.0.0.30
```

The `externalIPs` can be used from outside the cluster but you must route traffic to *any* node yourself, for example;

```
ip route add 222.0.0.30/32 \
  nexthop via 192.168.0.1 \
  nexthop via 192.168.0.2 \
  nexthop via 192.168.0.3
```

Assuming yous k8s nodes have ip 192.168.0.x. This will setup ECMP routes to your nodes. When you make a request from outside the cluster to 222.0.0.30:8545 k8s will load-balance between your *ready* PODs.

Comment: Thanks ! I appreciate the clear answer. In the first case it seem that I've got problem... The status is pending. I've tried the second way then and the External IP but it's steel impossible for me to ping the external IP... Any ideas ? Maybe because of rke ?

Comment: You can never ping a service (external or internal) in k8s since ICMP-echo is not forwarded. However TCP connect works anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For loadbalancing and exposing your pods, you can use https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

and for checking when a pod is ready, you can use tweak your liveness and readiness probes as explained https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/

for probes you might want to consider exec actions like execution a script that checks what is required and returning 0 or 1 dependent on status.

Comment: Was literally writing the same thing haha!

Comment: @FrankYuchengGu yes, it does happen in open forums :)

Comment: For the loadBalancing, I've already seen those doc pages but I don't undertand the way it's works. Why the client is in the node ? Why is there always a kubeProxy ? And where is the service ?

Comment: For the liveness and readiness I've already done it. I was just explaining more precisely my idea but the question was just about the way to load balance. Sorry about this confusion !

Comment: load balancing is implemented with in services.

Answer (score 0):

When a container is started, Kubernetes can be configured to wait for a configurable
amount of time to pass before performing the first readiness check. After that, it
invokes the probe periodically and acts based on the result of the readiness probe. If a
pod reports that it’s not ready, it’s removed from the service. If the pod then becomes
ready again, it’s re-added.
Unlike liveness probes, if a container fails the readiness check, it won’t be killed or
restarted. This is an important distinction between liveness and readiness probes.
Liveness probes keep pods healthy by killing off unhealthy containers and replacing
them with new, healthy ones, whereas readiness probes make sure that only pods that
are ready to serve requests receive them. This is mostly necessary during container
start up, but it’s also useful after the container has been running for a while.

**I think you can use probe for your goal**